# re enable Always show pre-publish checks WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

[image]

I have unchecked the option of `Always show pre-publish checks.` at the bottom during publishing a WordPress post. Now i can not find it in any settings to re-enable this option. Is there any option in WP admin to get this option back again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually re-enable it straight from any post/new-post page on the admin side.

`Publishing bar` > `3-dots` symbol > `Preferences` (at the bottom) > `General` > `Include pre-published checklist`

[image]

[image]